# Draw a filled triangle in DrawingContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

*This is a follow up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725686/how-to-best-display-large-number-of-items-in-program).*

### Question:

I am trying to draw a filled triangle using `DrawingContext`, which is rendered on a `DrawingVisual`

Currently, I have managed to draw the outline of a triangle using the following C# code:

```
private DrawingVisual CreateTriangle()
  {
     DrawingVisual triangle = new DrawingVisual();
     using ( DrawingContext dc = triangle.RenderOpen() )
     {
         Pen drawingPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black,3);
         dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(0, 50), new Point(50, 0));
         dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(50, 0), new Point(50, 100));
         dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(50, 100), new Point(0, 50));

     }
     return triangle;
  }
```

I get this:

[image: Unfilled Triangle]

How do I draw a triangle that, in addition to th border I have drawn also has a red fill?

[image: Filled Triangle]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `dc.DrawGeometry` to create filled-in shapes.

Edit: This:

```
private DrawingVisual CreateTriangle()
{
    var triangle = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = triangle.RenderOpen())
    {
       var start = new Point(0, 50);

       var segments = new []
       { 
          new LineSegment(new Point(50,0), true), 
          new LineSegment(new Point(50, 100), true)
       };

       var figure = new PathFigure(start, segments, true);
       var geo = new PathGeometry(new [] { figure });
       dc.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Red, null, geo);

       var drawingPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);
       dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(0, 50), new Point(50, 0));
       dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(50, 0), new Point(50, 100));
       dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(50, 100), new Point(0, 50));   
    }

    return triangle;
}
```

On a side note, if you have to create the `PathGeometry` anyway and you use `DrawGeometry` you might as well stroke it too, then you don't need your original line drawings.

```
dc.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Red, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3), geo);
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a bit old but it might help somebody else. Instead of using PathGeometry it uses Stream geometry. "*This geometry is light-weight alternative to PathGeometry*"

```
Point p1 = new Point(0, 50);
Point p2 = new Point(50, 0);
Point p3 = new Point(50, 100);
StreamGeometry streamGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
using (StreamGeometryContext geometryContext = streamGeometry.Open())   
{
    geometryContext.BeginFigure(p1, true, true);
    PointCollection points = new PointCollection{ p2, p3 };
    geometryContext.PolyLineTo(points, true, true);
}

streamGeometry.Freeze();
context.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Red, new Pen(Brushes.Black,3), streamGeometry);
```

More info about StreamGeometry here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx

Regards.