# How can I draw a path with markers (Segments connection points)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, charts

I know how to draw a path in WPF by using the 
 [Path Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx)   and
 [Stream Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx)  .

I want to add a marker to each connection point in a manner similar to Matlab:
[image]

I can do a lot of small triangle geometries per marker, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this by overriding OnRender in your chart UserControl and drawing the path first, then markers second.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732869/draw-a-filled-triangle-in-drawingcontext).

In it the poster creates a Geometry to represent a triangle then uses the rendering context passed in to OnRender to draw the triangle repeatedly.

You might find if you have a large number of datapoints this method becomes quite slow. You can experiment instead with multiple small blits of a market bitmap to the rendering context, or using the WriteableBitmap API which provides direct access to bitmap & therefore immediate mode rendering.

**Edit:** You might also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713864/high-performance-graphics-using-the-wpf-visual-layer/8714107#8714107), which discusses high performance WPF graphics in general.

Best regards,