# WPF Image Border

Tags: wpf, image, border

I have this Image:

[image: ArrowImage]

I want the image to have a border
If I do:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Source="/<AppName>;component/Images/Background/Achtergrond_Arrow.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="22" >
                <Image.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF868686" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10"  />
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
        </Border>
```

it gives a Square border, not following the arrow itself.

[image: Square Image]

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an image but draw the border and triangle yourself. You can use a `Path`, a `Line` and other basic geometric shapes for this.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732869/draw-a-filled-triangle-in-drawingcontext) may give you a starting point. Or a [Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/04/Rounded-Graphics-in-WPF.html) blog post can give you further assistance.

Comment: And finally you just did it as supposed by your own answer. So you can safely mark my answer as Accepted ;)

Comment: you rly just doing this to get some accepted answers do you? :p

Comment: Thanx Zarkos. And, yes I have an ego that likes reputation ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Border in WPF is always rectangular.

If you want an outline you will have to draw it or [use an effect](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
<Path Fill="Black" Data="M 0 44 L 22 22 L 0 0 Z"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22" >
        <Path.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF868686" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10"  />
        </Path.Effect>
    </Path>
```

I threw the arrow image away.

Thanks anyway